# Knockoutjs subscribe event , ko.computed execution timing issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to set different value to self.selectedTitleId() in knockoutjs when self.selectedQueryId changes, so i have added a subscribe to selectedQueryId.
I have another computed variable self.text which format the self.selectedTitleId with other variables.

My problem is , when i change the selectedQueryId value from UI, computed function gets called first, followed by subscribe call. Because of this, the text that i am trying to display always holds the previous selection value.

I want to hold the self.text computed function execution until selectedTitleId.subscribe function is completed so that self.selectedTitleId has current value.

Can someone help me? Thanks for your time!

Below is the html component which is used to bing selectedTitleId value with UI. backend js always shows the 'backendName' as value, even though i tried to set a different value using self.selectedTitleId("newValue").
         html:

```
      var sformat = (function() {
       var pattern = /\{\{|\}\}|\{(\d+)\}/g;
         return function () {
         var parameters = arguments;
         if(parameters[0]) {
           console.log(parameters[0])
           return parameters[0].replace(pattern, function (match, group) {
             var value;
              if (match === "{{")
                return "{";
              if (match === "}}")
                return "}";
             value = parameters[parseInt(group, 10) + 1];
             return value ? value.toString() : "";
            });
         }
       };
     });

       function test() {
         return sformat.apply(this, arguments);
       }

       self.selectedTitleId = ko.observable('');

       self.text = ko.computed(function () {
        console.log("inside text function")

        if (self.selectedTitleId && self.selectedQueryId()) {
          console.log(self.selectedTitleId)
          self.displayField = test(self.selectedTitleId, self.selectedQueryId(),self.queryValue());
        }else if(self.selectedTitleId && self.selectedQueryId() && self.queryGreaterValue() &&   self.queryLesserValue()){
          self.displayField = test(self.selectedTitleId, self.selectedQueryId(),self.queryValue(),self.queryGreaterValue(),self.queryLesserValue());
        }
     return self.displayField;
    });

    self.selectedQueryId.subscribe(function (newValue) {

        $.getJSON("json/queries.json", function (allData) {
            var mappedData = $.map(allData, function (item) {
                if(item.DisplayName == "Price"){
                    if(newValue == "range") {
                        self.selectedTitleId(item.RangeBackEndFieldName);
                        console.log("range");
                        console.log(item.RangeBackEndFieldName); //Prints new string
                        console.log(self.selectedTitleId()); //Print old value- 
                    }else if(newValue == "$gt:" || newValue == "$lt:"){
                        self.selectedTitleId(item.BackendFieldName);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something else you are not telling us, it doesn't make sense for `selectedTitleId` to be a `ko.computed`. Just use a regular observable:

```
self.selectedTitleId = ko.observable();

self.selectedQueryId.subscribe(function (newValue) {

    $.getJSON("json/queries.json", function (allData) {
        var mappedData = $.map(allData, function (item) {
            if(item.DisplayName == "Price"){
                if(newValue == "range") {
                    self.selectedTitleId(item.RangeBackEndFieldName);
                    });
                }else if(newValue == "$gt:" || newValue == "$lt:"){
                    self.selectedTitleId(item.BackendFieldName);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now when `selectedTitleId` is changed in your callback, it should trigger `text` to re-evaluate.

The problem with your original wasn't that it was updating `text` first, it was that it wasn't re-evaluating when you changed `selectedTitleId`. See here:

```
if (self.selectedTitleId() && self.selectedQueryId()) {
```

This means your `computed` property is dependent on both `selectedTitleId` and `selectedQueryId`, updating either will cause the function to run again. But in your original code, you completely replaced `self.selectedTitleId` with an entirely new function, but your `computed` is still dependent on the old one (which is unchanged).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes you are right. I was trying to make this a function to get the sformat function working. sformat function is used to mimic String.format function in java which replaces {0} {1}...in a given string with passed arguments..

Comment: I tried passing self.selectedTitleId to this sformat through the test method, but I always get TypeError: parameters[0].replace is not a function. when i tried debuggin what is parameters[0], it gave me d(). I want to pass the string to test method. If i made self.selectedTitleId a function, I was able to pass self.selectedTitleId() into test method and format worked fine..This is my exact problem..to get this I went changing selectedTitleID to a function which caused computed function issue..

Comment: @user3773712: Your observable is a function (functionally, it's pretty much exactly what you had in your `computed`), so to pass the value *inside* the observable, you just call that function. So `myfunction(self.selectedTitleId())` will pass the value from your observable to the `myfunction`. So as far as I can understand what you are doing, you should be able to use the observable exactly like you were using the computed.

Comment: I just edited my question. After making self.selectedTitleId("newValue") line i tried few console.log to see if the self.selectedTitleId value got changed. But it did not change at all. When i tried ko.computed the value got changed.

Comment: It's hard to tell with only part of the code, but where is your definition of `self.selectedTitleId`? I also notice that you change the `if` statement in your `text` computed. That should still be `self.selectedTitleId()` because `self.selectedTitleId` will always return a function (if you did, indeed make it an observable) and that is always truthy.

Comment: I have added the html component using which i binded this element. It always gives me the value that i set in the UI. self.selectedTitleId("newValue") did not take effect at all. I am very new to javascript world. I have been trying to make jsfiddle of this project. because of the size and the dependency I could not make one yet :(